# InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error at SqlDataReader.Close()

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have legacy code with the logic as seen here:

```
using (SqlDataReader drColor = ColorDal.GetColors())
{
   if (drColor.HasRows)
   {
      string colorCacheKey = string.Empty;
      //_log.Debug("Total Color Count loaded from database: " + dsColor.Tables.Count.ToString());

      // Retrieve each colorfamily present in the dataset.
      while (drColor.Read())
      {
         ......
      }
   }

   drColor.Close(); // This is line # in the exception.
}
```

Intermittently I am getting the following exception in my ASP.NET MVC app:

> [InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +6355814
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
>   +308
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close() +293

Could closing the `SqlDataReader` inside `using{}` be the cause of it?

Thanks.

Comment: When the using block exits, it should call close and dispose, so while that is likely not the culprit, the code is unnecesary anyways.

Comment: Tejs is right - 'using' is the right way to go. The .Close() isn't needed, but that's not causing your problem. I suspect something is happening to the conneection during the read - perhaps another thread closing it?

Comment: I know that when exiting using block, it closes and disposes of the connections, but the stack trace mentions the line # in which the datareader is being closed, hence I am getting a bit confused reg the reason for the error.

Answer (score -1):

This may help...not sure where they're at with this bug, but it might give you a place to start:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772492/internal-connection-fatal-error-system-invalidoperationexception